# Error when mixing export default and named exports

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a module (lib-my-search-result ) has an index.tsx file that works as expected when it just has:

**export default index**;

but I would like to export some component in this module so , I added named exports like the following :

**export {CatalogueCover, ItemImage, ItemField, EntityDetailLink}**

but the problem that I am getting a warning message during **yarn build**

and the module is not working as before, but the named exports work.

The error message :

Entry module "src/index.tsx" is using named and default exports together. Consumers of your bundle will have to use `libMySearchResult["default"]` to access the default export, which may not be what you want. Use `output.exports: "named"` to disable this warning

Any idea ?